# Remove 'Disqus' from header part

Tags: drupal, comments, disqus

I use 'disqus' module on my drupal8 website.
Does anybody knows how to remove or re-write this:

[image]

I couldn't find the answer on the internet so I thought maybe someone here knows the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. View the manage display tab of the content type that implements the disqus comments field and set the label to Hidden and save.

To access the manage display page, go to: admin/structure/types then in the operations column, select "Manage display".